# Android TextView breaking lines incorrectly

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I have a problem using a TextView within a ListView where the TextView is breaking the line incorrectly.

For the purposes of illustrating the problem, I have the following text to display:

```
"12345678901234567 ="
"12345678901 ="
"12345678901234567 *"
```

The xml (TextView) I am using is as follows:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="end"
    android:textAlignment="gravity"
    android:layout_gravity="end"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
/>
```

The Resulting display is as follows:

```
   123456789
    01234567
           =
12345678901=
   123456789
    01234567
           *
```

Obviously I don't want the "=" and "*" to be on a separate line. I have
tried dozens of different xml variations without achieving what I want.

The emulators tested are :

Nexus 6 API 23:5556

Nexus6p API 23:5556

MotoG3  Android 6

Compiled for Android 6 using 23.0.3

Using the following xml (EditText), I do get the desired result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<EditText xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="end"
    android:textAlignment="gravity"
    android:layout_gravity="end"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:editable="false">
</EditText>
```

The correct result is as follows:

```
12345678901234
         567 =
 12345678901 =
12345678901234
         567 *
```

While I could use the EditText, the display should not be editable
and I believe that TextView should work. Also, "android:editable"
is deprecated.

Can someone reading this advise me either how to get the TextView
to work as required, or alternatively how to use the EditText with
a non-deprecated feature and achieve the desired result?

.........   added to question ----------

The code used to create the ListView in test prog is as follows:-

```
private void createLayout() {

    RelativeLayout wRelLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);

    wRelLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.DKGRAY);

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams jLayParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(500, 700);

    setContentView(wRelLayout, jLayParams);

    ArrayList<String> alCalcLines = new ArrayList();
    ListView lvCalcLines = new ListView(this);
    lvCalcLines.setX(10);
    lvCalcLines.setY(10);
    lvCalcLines.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
    lvCalcLines.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
    lvCalcLines.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<>(
            this, R.layout.text_view_1, alCalcLines));  // xml

    jLayParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

    wRelLayout.addView(lvCalcLines, jLayParams);

    alCalcLines.add("12345678901234567 =");
    alCalcLines.add("12345678901 =");
    alCalcLines.add("12345678901234567 *");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your Edit text XML,works for me.

```
<EditText
    android:clickable="false" 
    android:cursorVisible="false" 
    android:focusable="false" 
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"/>
```

Comment: I may look at that, however it is a TextView, and the TextView should handle it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

> Try these in Textview or edittext

```
 txt_view.setTextDirection(View.TEXT_DIRECTION_RTL);
```

or

```
 txt_view.setTextDirection(View.TEXT_DIRECTION_ANY_RTL);
```

> Also in android:supportsRtl="true" to the  application
>
> In xml

```
 android:textDirection="rtl"
```

set gravity to right

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want a word (in your case "=" is the word since it is separated with spaces) not to be transferred to next line, you can use a **non-breaking space**.
It is `\u00A0` in Android. So your String looks like this:

```
"12345678901234567\u00A0="
"12345678901\u00A0="
"12345678901234567\u00A0*"
```

Comment: I put "\u00A0" in the TextView and it appears to work OK. Is the default to always break on spaces? I'll give it a tick if no better answer comes soon. It seems to me it would be easier to put a newline if a break is required, but perhaps I'm missing something.

Comment: @briano, only if the second word is too long to fit a `TextView`. If the answer is correct, then pls accept it

Comment: That's not the case here though. It should fit in two lines.

Comment: @briano, I can try to figure out why it works this way if you show the xml, where your ListView is placed

Comment: OK thanks, got to go now. I'll do later. It's in code.

Comment: I've added the code used to create the ListView to the question.

Answer (score -1):

add [android:SingleLine="true"] in textview line